# Question on definite integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How to compute the following:

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\tan^{-1}(ax)}{x(1+x^2)}dx $$

If you could, please, solve it completely, for, I am afraid, a hint won't do for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set $$\vartheta(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\tan^{-1}(ax)}{x(1+x^2)}dx$$

Differentiate and use partial fractions to integrate.

*Spoiler*

> $$\vartheta '(a) = \int_0^\infty  {\frac{1}{{1 + {a^2}{x^2}}}\frac{1}{{1 + {x^2}}}} dx$$

and

> $$\frac{1}{{1 + {a^2}{x^2}}}\frac{1}{{1 + {x^2}}} = \frac{1}{{1 - {a^2}}}\left( {\frac{1}{{1 + {x^2}}} - \frac{{{a^2}}}{{1 + {a^2}{x^2}}}} \right)$$

Then use that

> $$\int_0^\infty  {\frac{{dx}}{{1 + {x^2}}}} = \frac{\pi}2$$

to obtain

> $$\vartheta '(a) = \frac{1}{{1 - {a^2}}}\left( {\frac{\pi }{2} - a\frac{\pi }{2}} \right) = \frac{{1 - a}}{{1 - {a^2}}}\frac{\pi }{2} = \frac{\pi }{2}\frac{1}{{1 + a}}$$

And I guess you can take it from there.

**ADD** Note I missed a detail on the integral $$\int_0^\infty  {\frac{{{a^2}}}{{1 + {a^2}{x^2}}}dx} $$ If $a>0$, we have that $$a\int_0^\infty  {\frac{1}{{1 + {{\left( {ax} \right)}^2}}}d\left( {ax} \right)}  = a\int_0^\infty  {\frac{1}{{1 + {t^2}}}dt}  = \frac{{\pi a}}{2}$$ but if $a<0$ $$a\int_0^\infty  {\frac{1}{{1 + {{\left( {ax} \right)}^2}}}d\left( {ax} \right)}  = a\int_0^{ - \infty } {\frac{1}{{1 + {t^2}}}dt}  =  - \frac{{\pi a}}{2}$$ Thus in any case $$\vartheta'(a)=\frac{1}{{1 - {{\left| a \right|}^2}}}\left( {\frac{\pi }{2} - \left| a \right|\frac{\pi }{2}} \right) = \frac{\pi }{2}\frac{1}{{1 + \left| a \right|}}$$

Comment: This works for $a>0$. I would add that since $I(a)$ is odd as a function of $a$, we can extend it easily to negative values of $a$.

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien Why would it not work for $a<0$?

Comment: take for example $a=-2$, you'd get $0$ with $I(a)=\pi/2\ln(|a+1|)$

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien I have found my mistake-.

Comment: Works perfectly that way as well +1

Answer (score 5):

Let $\displaystyle I(a) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\tan^{-1}(ax)}{x.(1+x^2)}dx$

Now Diff. both side w.r.to $a$ , We Get

$\displaystyle \frac{dI(a)}{da} = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+a^2x^2).x.(1+x^2)}.x.dx$

$\displaystyle \frac{dI(a)}{da} = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+x^2).(1+a^2x^2)}dx$

$\displaystyle \frac{dI(a)}{da} = \frac{1}{(a^2-1)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{a^2}{1+a^2x^2}-\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)dx$

$\displaystyle \frac{dI(a)}{da}= \frac{a}{(a^2-1)}.\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{(a^2-1)}.\frac{\pi}{2}$

$\displaystyle \frac{dI(a)}{da} = \frac{\pi}{2}.\frac{1}{a+1}$

Now $\displaystyle \int \frac{dI(a)}{da}da = \frac{\pi}{2}\int\frac{1}{a+1}da$

$\displaystyle I(a) =\frac{\pi}{2}.\ln |a+1|+C$

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Comment: Use $I(0)=0$ to clear that $C$

Comment: No Peter Tamaroff I have not see yours answer, when I post my answer after then i have seen it. If i have seen yours answer that i will not post it,Thanks Jean-Sébastien I missed it.

Comment: No problem! ;) ${}{}$

Comment: Peter, to be fair, juan posted this only 8 minutes after you posted yours.  It looks like it took a lot longer than 8 minutes to put this together, so I would give him the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: @RonGordon Sorry if I came out as accusing. That wasn't the intention.

Comment: Hey man, it's all good.

Comment: This works for $a>0$. I would add that since I(a) is odd as a function of a, we can extend it easily to negative values of $a$.